# java - exception handing

Tags: java, exception

I created this program that should let the user enter the loan amount and loan period in the number of years from text fields, and it should display the monthly and total payments for each interest rate starting from 5 percent to 8 percent, with increments of one-eighth, in a text area. This may sound stupid but not sure how to add exception handling to add exception handling for when a non-numeric value is entered.For example instead of entering 5 for the number of years, the user enters five.The application should display an error message. thanks in advance.
package loan;

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;

public class loan extends Application {
    protected TextField tfLoanAmount = new TextField();
    protected TextField tfNumberOfYears = new TextField();
    protected TextArea textArea = new TextArea();

    @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        tfNumberOfYears.setPrefColumnCount(2);
        tfLoanAmount.setPrefColumnCount(7);
        textArea.setPrefColumnCount(30);

        // Create a button
        Button btShowTable = new Button("Show Table");

        // Create a hbox
        HBox paneForControls = new HBox(10);
        paneForControls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        paneForControls.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Loan Amount"), tfLoanAmount,
            new Label("Number of Years"), tfNumberOfYears, btShowTable);

        // Create a scrollPane
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(textArea);

        // Create a pane
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setTop(paneForControls);
        pane.setCenter(textArea);

        // Create and register handler
        btShowTable.setOnAction(e -> {
            print();
        });

        // Create a scene and place it in the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setTitle("loans"); // Set the stage title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
    }

    private void print() {
        // Create a output string
        String output = "";
        double monthlyInterestRate; // Monthly interest rate
        double monthlyPayment;  // Monthly payment

        // Add table header
        output += "Interest Rate       Monthly Payment          Total Payment\n";

        // Calculate and add table with interest rates to output
        for (double i = 5.0; i <= 8; i += 0.125) {
            monthlyInterestRate = i / 1200;
            monthlyPayment = Double.parseDouble(tfLoanAmount.getText()) * 
                monthlyInterestRate / (1 - 1 / Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterestRate,
                Double.parseDouble(tfNumberOfYears.getText()) * 12));

            output += String.format("%-24.3f%-34.2f%-8.2f\n", i, 
                monthlyPayment, (monthlyPayment * 12) * 
                Double.parseDouble(tfNumberOfYears.getText()));
        }

        textArea.setText(output);
    }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you already tried before? Where in your code would the exception handling need to be? Dumping all your code on SO won't net you many answers.

Comment: Oh my. This is something that you can easily google which is the reason for the down votes (by others).  They aren't being mean, just trying to limit clutter.  If (!(isNumerc(tfLoanAmount.getText()))) {throw new IllegalArgumentException();}   public static boolean isNumeric(String str)
{
    return str.matches("-?\\d+(.\\d+)?");
}

Answer (score 0):

TextField(tfNumberOfYears) [TextField]: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html,
this TextField has a method `public final String getText()`, this method returns a String.

When you use [`Double.parseDouble(tfNumberOfYears.getText())`]: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html

`public static double parseDouble(String s) throws NumberFormatException`

Throws:

NullPointerException - if the string is null

NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable double.

So you can put that code inside a try/catch block and make what you desire when the user enters five instead of 5.

Like:

```
`private void print() {
    // Create a output string
    String output = "";
    double monthlyInterestRate; // Monthly interest rate
    double monthlyPayment;  // Monthly payment

    // Add table header
    output += "Interest Rate       Monthly Payment          Total Payment\n";

    // Calculate and add table with interest rates to output
    for (double i = 5.0; i <= 8; i += 0.125) {
        monthlyInterestRate = i / 1200;
        try{
            monthlyPayment = Double.parseDouble(tfLoanAmount.getText()) * 
            monthlyInterestRate / (1 - 1 / Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterestRate,
            Double.parseDouble(tfNumberOfYears.getText()) * 12));
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){
            //Here you write the code to manage this exception

        }
        try{
            output += String.format("%-24.3f%-34.2f%-8.2f\n", i, 
            monthlyPayment, (monthlyPayment * 12) * 
            Double.parseDouble(tfNumberOfYears.getText()));
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){
            //Here you write the code to manage this exception

        }
    }

    textArea.setText(output);
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args); 
}`
```

This is just an example of how to handle that exception.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many ways to approach this, some I can think of off the top of my head are if statements if you know what kinds of errors to expect, regex matching to only filter on valid input, or try/catches, for example

```
// if the userinput string matches a number
if( userInputNumber.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?") ) {
    // put your code here
else {
    System.out.println("Input unrecognized. Please type in a number (e.g. "5")
}
```

or perhaps

```
try {
    double userInputNumber = Double.parseDouble(loan.getText());
    // do some code
catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("Error, unrecognized input.");
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```